# Finding Max and Min values from a MongoDB Repository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-repositories

Is it possible to get the max and min values of a specific field within a repository within Spring Boot? If so, how do you do it?

I understand it is very easy using Mongo Shell.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/

I've been investigating for a while now and still haven't come up with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

```
public interface OrderRepository extends MongoRepository<Order,String> {

// Find MAX Value

Order findTopByOrderByOrderDateDesc();

// Find MIN Value

Order findTopByOrderByOrderDateAsc();

}
```